# Does exist an SMT solver supporting theories on differential equations?

Tags: ode, smt

if so, how does it work? I tried to find information on z3 about differential equations but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `dReal` (http://dreal.github.io/) is the only solver that provides support for ODEs, though I’m not an expert on this.

Also, see this paper for further details: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.8278.pdf